# How do I set initial sorting on a TreeView

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have some tabular data that I want to display in a table. And I do want to be able to sort the data by clicking the headers. All this works fine but I cant figure out how to set the **initial sorting** of the table.

When I run the example below the data is presented in the order I inserted it into the `ListStore`, this is because there is no specific column selected for sorting yet. But I would like the **C**-column to be selected for sorting when the app fires up.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                          
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                        

import gtk                                                                     

class TreeViewExample:                                                         
    def __init__(self):                                                        
        self.window = gtk.Window()                                             
        self.box = gtk.VBox()                                                  
        self.window.add(self.box)                                              

        data = [                                                               
                [ 10, 40, 17 ],                                                
                [ 20, 30, 14 ],                                                
                [ 30, 20, 15 ],                                                
                [ 40, 10, 19 ],                                                
                ]                                                              
        store = gtk.ListStore(int, int, int)                                   
        for row in data:                                                       
            store.append(row)                                                  

        treeView = gtk.TreeView()                                              
        treeView.set_model(store)                                              

        for i, col_name in enumerate('ABC'):                                   
            renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()                                  
            column = gtk.TreeViewColumn(col_name, renderer, text=i)            
            column.set_sort_column_id(i)                                       
            treeView.append_column(column)                                     

        self.box.pack_start(treeView)                                          
        self.window.show_all()                                                 

    def main(self):                                                            
        gtk.main()                       

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                     
    TreeViewExample().main()
```

Comment: If my answer worked, please accept it for other people coming here.

Answer (score 0):

You could programatically [click](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeViewColumn.html#Gtk.TreeViewColumn.clicked) the column using `column.clicked()`.

As an aside, you are using Gtk2, which is deprecated. Please consider using Gtk3 with

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
```